# Можно ли упростить представление таблиц в Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

Есть такая особенность в Hibernate, если у таблицы есть отношение к другой таблице, то в классе представления первой, переменная должна хранить ссылку на объект второй, а не ее значение.

Вопрос мой таков: **Можно ли как-то настроить "Гиперсеть", чтобы в представлениях просто разместить примитивную переменную а не ссылку на другую таблицу?**

В первый раз мне это помогало, но сейчас попусту не нужно, а порой даже усложняет работу. (уж очень много отношений)

Comment: Это зависит от типа связи. Иногда можно вообще никаких связей не указывать.

Comment: Один ко многим. По крайней мере подавляющая часть. (Если не все)

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, в зависимых элементах, вообще не обязательно указывать ссылку на то, от кого они зависят, при один ко многим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что вы хотите получить?

Мы не выводим в форме "Ученик 7б класса - Человек_117 (перейдите по ссылке чтобы узнать его фамилию)", но "Ученик 7б класса - Вася Иванов".

Но если очень хочется, то можно сделать вместо

```
puplic class Scholar {
  //...
  @OneToOne
  private Person person;
  //...
}
```

Написать следующее

```
puplic class Scholar {
  //...
  @Column
  private String personId;
  //...
}
```

Во втором случае все операции по работе с дочерним объектом нужно будет реализовывать самостоятельно.